# Returning value from module

Tags: vb.net

I can't seem to return the counter value at the end of the routine.

```
Sub CountCheckBoxes(sldTemp As Slide)
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim shpTemp As Shape
    For Each shpTemp In sldTemp.Shapes
        If shpTemp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            If TypeName(shpTemp.OLEFormat.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
                If shpTemp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
                    counter = counter + 1             
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return counter
End Function
```

EDIT
NEW CODE: Problem is when I type `Return Counter` then hit enter. The reason I have this function is to count how many of my checkboxes on a slide are true then return the value:

```
Function CountCheckBoxes(sldTemp As Slide) As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim shpTemp As Shape

    For Each shpTemp In sldTemp.Shapes
        If shpTemp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
           If TypeName(shpTemp.OLEFormat.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
              If shpTemp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
                 counter = counter + 1
              End If
           End If
        End If
    Next
    Return counter 
End Function
```

Comment: You need to change the method from a `Sub` to a `Function`.  Also, you should have it specify the return type, like `Function CountCheckBoxes(sldTemp As Slide) As Integer`

Comment: By the way, that whole method body could be written in one line using LINQ: `Return sldTemp.Shapes.Count(Function(shpTemp) shpTemp.Type = msoOLEControlObject AndAlso TypeName(shpTemp.OLEFormat.Object) = "CheckBox" AndAlso shpTemp.OLEFormat.Object.Value)`. At the very least, don't use three separate `If` statements when you only need one with three conditions: `If shpTemp.Type = msoOLEControlObject AndAlso TypeName(shpTemp.OLEFormat.Object) = "CheckBox" AndAlso shpTemp.OLEFormat.Object.Value Then`.

Comment: One point to note is that, if `sldTemp.Shapes` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable(Of T)`, as seems likely, then you might need to throw in a `Cast` there too: `.Shapes.Cast(Of Shape)().Count(`

Comment: @StevenDoggart i did change it to a function and specified return type but it still gives me an error of "expected: end of statement" highlighting return counter

Comment: If it still doesn't work then you did it wrong. Show us the code you have now and also specify where EXACTLY the error occurs.

Comment: @jmcilhinney it is updated now

Comment: Then the problem must be elsewhere in the file, because there's nothing syntactically wrong with that function, as you posted it in the update.

Comment: Hmm ok i will try to look into it more and will update

Answer (score 2):

For fun:

```
Function CountCheckBoxes(sldTemp As Slide) As Integer
    Return sldTemp.Shapes.Count(Function(s) s.Type = msoOLEControlObject AndAlso TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object) = "CheckBox" AndAlso s.OLEFormat.Object.Value)
End Function
```

Comment: No way this code does everything OP was trying to do, it is too simple! ;)